# using omp threads inside function

Tags: c++, function, openmp, parallels

I'm trying to play a little with omp threads. Inorder to make "main" function more clean, I want to use omp threads inside function which called by the main function.
Here we have an example:

```cpp
void main()
{
    func();
}

void func()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

With complex computations, when running, after thread 0 finishes, the funcion returns while the other threads haven't finish yet. How can I suspend the return until all threads finishes?

Using barrier inside for loop is impossible, so I don't have another idea.

Comment: Your observation must be wrong. There is a thread barrier at the end of a parallel section. The main thread will not continue until all other threads have reached that point.

Comment: I guess your real-world program has an undefined behaviour (eg. race condition, buffer overflow, missing synchronizations, etc.) somewhere that could cause such issue. But without a minimal reproducible example, we cannot help you. If it is an OpenMP bug (unlikely but possible), then this minimal reproducible example is critical for the bug to be solved. If it is your program, then simplifying it will help you to better understand the issue. It is frequent for people to find the source of the bug while trying to write such an example ;) .